# Function and array of strings

Tags: string, function, arguments

How can i write a function that takes an array of strings as an argument and returns a sorted array containing the same strings ordered from shortest to longest?

Please help

Comment: in which language ?

Comment: In Python, you can do it by `arg_list.sort(key=len)`

Comment: Seriously, nobody can answer your question without knowing what language you're using.